# Disable Go button in iPhone with JavaScript

Tags: iphone

I'm creating small form for iPhone and on that form I do JavaScript validation (backed up by server validation of course but that is not the point).

As a result of this validation I enable/disable submit button dynamically. This work great except that "Go" button in on screen keyboard does not reflect the status of the only submit button I have and is always enabled.

Is there any way this can be fixed? Can I somehow disable that Go button with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The On Screen Keyboard can not be edited by JavaScript. You should just cancel submit events if the form didn't validate.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the `Go` button entirely by removing the form element. By that I mean maintain your inputs and selections but remove the `<form>` tags.

You can still submit/validate using jQuery but the `Go` button will be replaced by the `Return` button.

Answer (score 4):

Flavio's script works, but users may find it unintuitive if the Go button is disabled.

Instead of disabling the submit button, try disabling form submission.

```
<form id="myform" onSubmit="return canSubmit(this);">
...
</form>
```

The jQuery way of doing this is:

```
$('#myform').submit(canSubmit); 
/* where canSubmit is a function defined as 
'function canSubmit() {...}' returning true or false */
```

Answer (score 1):

use this javascript code inside the head tag and you will disable the go button for input types:text, number, tel, email.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   <!--disable enter key / go button iphone-->
   function stopRKey(evt) {
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : 
                               ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {return false;}
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="email")) {return false;}
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="tel")) {return false;}
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="number")) {return false;}
   }

   document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I can stop form from submitting in more elegant way, but the button will be there and will be active for user to click on

Comment: I used this and it worked well. However, the "Go" button is disabled in functionality, but it's not disabled in style. You can still click it, and the button presses, but nothing happens.