# iOS/Iphone How to avoid the presence of "Go" button while filling up a form in multipage

Tags: javascript, ios, forms, responsive-design

I own a responsive web mobile application (Javascript) that displays a form in multi step. 
Similar to [that](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router).

The whole works except an issue regarding UX.
As soon as I fill up an input text, the iphone keyboard shows the "Done" button (at the top of the keyboard) and also the "Go" button.

Of course, the "Go" button appears since the input is within a `<form>` markup but has no effect since the submit button **is not generated yet** (thanks to Angular ui-router states). It would be generated only when the user reachs the last page/step.
Only the "Done" button hides the keyboard so that user can fills up other inputs.

However, it leads to confusion for lambda user to push the Go button in the first steps/pages of the form, and notice that it does nothing. It does not even hide the virtual keyboard, as "Done" does.

Is there a way to avoid Iphone to suggest the "Go" buttton before the user fills up every mandatory fields until the last page/step?

Indeed, the ideal way would be to only display the button "Done" in the position of the button "Go".

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151426/detecting-if-user-pressed-go-or-hide-keyboard-button-uitextfield

Comment: @Mohit But using pure HTML/Javascript, is it possible? A responsive web application does not deal with Objective-C

Comment: your code is based on java script?

Comment: Yes, a full AngularJS application :) I could do it using Cordova (that I use for the native app), but my OP concerns the application running in the web browser (Safari mobile in this case).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765227/remove-search-and-go-button-on-keyboard-in-ios-web-app

Comment: Ohh :)  Thanks !! I was thinking about cancelling the submit too ;)

Comment: does it work??? another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561826/disable-go-button-in-iphone-with-javascript

Comment: I test it in a couple of hours, I have to go for some times. I'll let you know whether it works :)

Comment: which one is worked?? may i put it as answer?

Comment: Hummmm...sorry, in fact it doesn't work.. Angular is pretty touchy. I tried to avoid using `form` markup, and using it only on the last page, to trigger submit, but I have one directive than need a form to work..